# How to implement SAVE TRAN of MSSQL in PostgreSQL?

Tags: transactions, database-migration, plpgsql, postgresql-11

Looking forward for a equivalent code in PostgreSQL, especially how to implement `SAVE TRAN`, `@@trancount`, and `@@error`.

The below code is in MSSQL and has to be migrated:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [APPLY_TRANSCO_CASH]
  AS
 BEGIN
DECLARE 
    @trancount int,
    @error int,
    @rowcount int,
    @ret int
 SELECT @trancount = @@trancount
IF(@trancount <> 0)
BEGIN   
    SAVE TRAN tran_APPLY_TRANSC
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN tran_APPLY_TRANSC
END

UPDATE ELIOT_TMp
SET Country = 'v'
SELECT @error = @@error, @rowcount = @@rowcount
IF (@error <> 0)
BEGIN 
    SELECT @ret = -1
    GOTO Error
END
SELECT @ret = @rowcount
GOTO Normal_End

Normal_End:
    IF (@trancount=0)
    BEGIN
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END
    RETURN @ret
Error:

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION tran_APPLY_TRANSC
    RETURN @ret
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `save tran` establishes a savepoint, I think the equivalent would be:

```
create procedure apply_transco_cash(inout retcode int)
AS
$$
begin

  UPDATE eliot_tmp
    SET Country = 'v';

  -- this returns the number of affected rows
  GET DIAGNOSTICS recode = ROW_COUNT;

  commit;
    
exception 
   when others then 
     retcode := -1;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

To deal with errors, you use an [exception block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING) in PL/pgSQL which automatically establish an implicit savepoint (in this case "covering" the whole procedure starting with the first `begin`). Explicitly setting a savepoint is not necessary (and you can't rollback to a savepoint in PL/pgSQL)

`GET DIAGNOSTICS` [is used](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS) to retrieve the number of rows affected by the last statement.